# How do you reload your Python source into the console window in Eclipse/Pydev?

Tags: python, pydev

In other Python IDEs (PythonWin and Idle) it's possible to hit a key and have your current source file window reloaded into the console.  I find this useful when experimenting with a piece of code; you can call functions from the console interactively and inspect data structures there.

Is there a way to do this with Eclipse/Pydev?

So far I've been making do with this hack in my source file:

```
def relo():
    execfile("/Path/To/Source.py", __builtins__)
```

I call `relo()` in the console after I save changes to the source.  But I'd much rather just tap a key.  I'm using pydev 1.4.7.2843.

This is somewhat related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323581/eclipse-pydev-is-it-possible-to-assign-a-shortcut-to-send-selection-to-the-pyt) question, but I want to just reload the whole source file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the latest [Pydev](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html) for details on what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> provides as it can do a number of things related to the interactive console.

Answer (score 1):

Use the revert option on the File menu.

You can bind a key to it in Windows > Preferences > General > Keys.

Edit:

The reload(module) function will update packages in the interactive console.  It's built in for python 2.x and in the imp module for 3.x.
Python docs link: http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/imp.html?#imp.reload

Couldn't find a way to run it by hotkey, I'd like to know if you find a way.

Comment: "Revert" just resets the text editor to the source file saved on disk.  It does nothing to load the file into the Python interpreter running in the Eclipse console pane.

Comment: sorry, misunderstood the question.  Updated answer.